# How to create a custom order to display posts and taxonomies

Tags: php, wordpress, sql-order-by

i'm a music producer and new to coding. I'm working on my website and i have created a custom taxonomy called "genre" which is linked to a custom post type called "my-music". below is the code i used for the options when adding genres to display on a page. please see the attached image for reference. a[this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fej1N.png) (https://drive.google.com/file/d/1liovGGOnjgx-IxjMklk1ZVNyyCaBpqXF/view?usp=sharing).

```
<?php if (!defined('FW')) die('Forbidden');
`$options = array(
'genre_heading'   => array(
    'label'   => __('Title', 'miraculous'),
    'type'    => 'text'
),
'number_limits'   => array(
    'label'   => __('Number of genre', 'miraculous'),
    'type'    => 'text'
),
);
```

The above code and attached image then display the created values under the genre taxonomy. please this image for reference. ( https://drive.google.com/file/d/191ArcB0y1sh9vuKynkknHrhP7GOCJ7Sv/view?usp=sharing ). by Default it display the genres by alphabetical order, i would like to add an option to the above codes called display order which should include 3 select options 1. Most Played 2.Alphabetical Order 3.Top Rated.

The "my-music' custom post type already has a function called (miraculous_song_view_counter) which counts how many times a song has been played. this is the code i used to create it ( https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kbcHW476CvFH5xIsjsXT0PIDtUIgLOVE/view?usp=sharing ). and i'm using Unyson feedback extension for rating posts. Is there a way to use the data collected from this rating submissions and music count function to create those display order options?